# Session is lost on change of the view PHP / CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I´m developing an app, and I´m using session variables to identify the logged user, all works fine until I change the view from the index. This is my login controller

```
$this->session->set_userdata('id', $obj[0]->ID);
header('Location: mydomain.com/landing');
```

I have not problem with this, actually, if I do

```
echo $this->session->userdata('id');
```

It returns the previous information stored on the session.

I loaded the session librery on autoload.php file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

When I try to load the landing view, exists a validation to know who is logged

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  if( !$this->session->has_userdata('id') ){
    header('Location: midominio.com');
  }
  else{
?>
<html></html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Every time it redirects me to the index, if I print the `$this->session` it returns

```
object(CI_Session)#16 (4) {
  ["userdata"]=>
  &array(1) {
    ["__ci_last_regenerate"]=>
    int(1537469720)
  }
  ["_driver":protected]=>
  string(5) "files"
  ["_config":protected]=>
  &array(9) {
    ["cookie_lifetime"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["cookie_name"]=>
    string(10) "ci_session"
    ["cookie_path"]=>
    string(1) "/"
    ["cookie_domain"]=>
    string(29) "mydomain.com"
    ["cookie_secure"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["expiration"]=>
    int(7200)
    ["match_ip"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["save_path"]=>
    string(34) "/opt/alt/php70/var/lib/php/session"
    ["_sid_regexp"]=>
    string(12) "[0-9a-v]{32}"
  }
  ["_sid_regexp":protected]=>
  string(12) "[0-9a-v]{32}"
}
```

Id from the login is not set. What is wrong?
I´m using PHP7 and CI 3x

Answer (score 0):

Please set below variables in config files.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

If ci_sessions table is not exists then please create below table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```